# Editing Breadcrum Html in MVCSiteMapProvider 2.3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mvcsitemapprovider

I've installed MVCSiteMapProvider via nuget for my MVC2 project, but I'm having trouble tweaking the display of the breadcrumb. Basically any changes I make to the helper file are not reflected in the browser, I can even comment the whole thing out but it still renders correctly on the page, just with the default markup.

I want to added a couple of classes to the Html to help me style the breadcrumb menu. I've tried searching the entire project for a fragments of the rendered markup but that returns no results, causing me to think the code that builds up the Html is locked away in the DLL. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or how I can acheive what I want?

Thanks in advance!

The markup I want (that is being ignored) is in the SiteMapPathHelperModel.ascx file:

```
<% foreach (var node in Model)
{ %>
    <div class="node-left"></div>
    <div class="node-label">
        <%=Html.DisplayFor(m => node)%>
    </div>
    <div class="node-right"></div>

<% if (node != Model.Last())
   { %>
        &gt;
<% } %>
```

I build the breadcrumb using

```
<div id="breadCrumb">
   <%= Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath() %>
</div>
```

Comment: Other than SiteMapPathHelperModel.ascx, do you also have the SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml file?

Comment: I do but I'm not using Razor, as I'm using MVC2. For this reason I haven't included SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml in my project, though I do have a copy of the file.

Comment: Are there a reason for not using the new version 3.2.2? Could you try to upgrade?

Comment: I started out with 3.2.2 but could not get it working with MVC2, so I switched to the older version. The rest of the project is too old large to upgrade to MVC3. I installed it with Nuget if that makes any difference.

Comment: Note that the .ascx/.cshtml files do not have to be included in the project to be picked up and used by the site/app. This has caught be out a couple of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little late, but I recently did this, also using MVC2 and no Razor. I made a new folder in Views/Shared/ called "DisplayTemplates", and in that folder I created a new .ascx file called "SiteMapPathHelperModel"...

The ascx file contains the following code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapPathHelperModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" %>
<ul id="crumbs">    
    <% foreach (var node in Model.Nodes) { %>
        <% if (!node.IsClickable)
           { %>
           <li><span class="noclick"><%=Html.DisplayFor(m => node)%></span>
        <%}
           else
           { %>
            <li><%=Html.DisplayFor(m => node)%>
        <%} %>
        <% if (node.Children.Any())
            { %>
           <%=Html.DisplayFor(m => node.Children)%>
        <% } %>
        </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Then it's just a simple matter of calling it correctly in your view. For this I did:

```
<div id="breadcrumbs">        
        <%= Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath() %>            
</div>
```

And everything worked just fine. I needed a certain markup so the CSS I wanted to use would work properly.